# I verbally accepted an offer.. can I renegotiate?

Tags: job-offer

I have been working in a very toxic office where I was really getting taken advantage of.

I started looking around in the same industry and secured a job interview. Things in my current office started working out and I told the interviewer that I may no longer be interested in a switch and cancelled my interview.

They called me very persistent and presented this amazing opportunity asking to just meet with me and explain.  Four interviews later I really started setting my mind and self up for a transition because of how amazing the offer looked.

Well yesterday  I sat down with them and the offer changed drastically.. I renegotiated some of it, but  I should have negotiated more. The new position is financially about the same now and not much better than my previous. The culture seems a little better and it has the potential to be great but that's just potential.

I told my previous  employer that I was making a transition, and since it is to a competitor they ended everything immediately.  I haven't signed the agreement  with the new brokerage  yet, but I have verbally agreed and am set to sign and start Monday.

Do I have any negotiation move here?  Can I say that I'll sign this as long as we revisit in 6 months?  Or am I screwed?  I don't want them to pull the offer but I could go to a different  brokerage  it will just take some time to line them up.

I like the culture there so far, but I'm worried about how different the offer was from what we discussed. They said it will be based on my performance, and that they are hesitant to connect me to all of their clients  until they see what I can do.

Comment: Ouch. I know you must realise this, but you should always be certain before you hand in your notice... If there were no pressure on getting another job, I'd say renegotiate, but that does carry a risk of the offer being withdrawn. Can you afford to support yourself while you find something else? Bear in mind that hunting without a job usually forces you to take worse offers as you don't have the luxury of time.

Comment: "*I renegotiated some of it, but I should have negotiated more.*" So you negotiated an offer, accepted it and now want to back out of that and renegotiate? You can try but there's no way to make that happen without damage to your reputation and the risk of having the offer pulled entirely.

Comment: "the offer changed drastically" - that's a red flag... they've strung you several interviews and then moved the goalposts, possibly hoping that you feel too invested in the process to back out

Answer (score 3):

Once you've accepted a verbal offer, they have to start writing up the official offer, which usually goes through an executive team and many other committees (depending on the size of the company) before they give it to you. This takes work and time. Work and time that they will have to do **again**. They will most likely pull the offer if you do this and find someone else.

But even if they don't, think about the good impressions you've left on your new employer up until this point. If you try to re-negotiate now, you will most likely damage the credibility. Think big picture. If they like you and you do well, the money will follow. Even if you re-negotiated and they gave you a small bump, your new boss may have ill feelings towards you and that will affect your long-term success at the company. First impressions take a long time to get over and sometimes you never do.

In addition, they may also think you are re-negotiating because you received a counter offer from your current employer and you are negotiating just because. This is also not advised.

At this point, you've made your decision and you should go with the new job. If anything, find another one once you start if you haven't job hopped too much. You also may end up loving the new job and you may find the money doesn't matter all that much. Good luck!

Comment: ehh this is half right. your new manager in a large firm is likely to not really care what HR had to do to recruit you. YMMV but I wouldn't be dire about it.

Answer (score 1):

> I haven't signed the agreement with the new brokerage yet but I have verbally agreed and am set to sign and start Monday. Do I have any negotiation move here?

No. In general, no, but starting in a few days, most certainly not.

> Can I say that I'll sign this as long as we revisit in 6 months?

No. That will get you nowhere as you will have no leverage in 6 months, and it is a bit antagonistic to say now.

> [Am] I screwed?

No, you go to work with the new firm on Monday and life goes on. But you are not in a position to increase your current offer with them. (Sidenote: did you give notice to your current firm...?)