# Accepted an offer, but forgot to consider the Cost of Living in that location; how should I proceed?

Tags: professionalism, job-offer

I accepted a startup Offer at Austin which is bump of 30 % from current Total Compensation, at Low Cost of Living.

I didn’t realize Austin is an area with a medium cost of living, and thus the real increased would only be 12 %. I don’t feel like switching for this small bump.

What options do I have here, or what do you suggest I can do to address this issue?

Comment: Took some major edits to the post, in the hopes of improving its readability and make the question more explicit. @KrishSingh please edit any details that I might have omitted, as well as any other details you can add that will help give better answers.

Comment: @jwh20 please don't answer in comments. I think that what you wrote is answer material

Comment: @DarkCygnus Good edits. Thought we had a similar question but only finding relates ones like: [Salary renegotiate after accepting the job offer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/43135) and [I verbally accepted an offer.. can I renegotiate?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/57716)

Comment: There are cheap places to live in Austin. Remember that it is a college town and students find places to live that don't cost that much. Secondly, once you are in Austin, there is huge competition for people with experience and you might be able to get a new job with a substantial salary bump.

Comment: How do you estimate the reduction of 18 %? Is it an estimation or have you collected experience of the costs, already?

Comment: @Bernhard.. from nerdwallet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options are obvious: Ask for more money, turn down the offer and keep looking, or take it as it is and make the best of it. Why are you asking here?

Comment: And recognize that you will completely burn bridges with everyone at the company that you accepted and might renege on.